# Need help with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have 2 forms that share a submit button. I have that part worked out, what I'm having trouble with is adding the validation to each form. Here is what I have, I have not done validation inside a submit function before, but usually on document ready.

```
$("#sbtBtn").click(function() {
          if($("input[name=license_code]").val()) { 
            $("#formOne").submit();
          } else if ($("input[name=referred_by_text]").val() && $("input[name=broker_text]").val() && $("input[name=email1]").val()) {
            $("#formTwo").submit();
          }
            else {
            //need help getting this added as an error message
             alert("Please fill out either the returning user or new user form");   
            }

    });

        $("#formOne").submit(function() {
            //need to put validation and AJAX submit here
        });

        $("#formTwo").submit(function() {
           //need to put validation and AJAX submit here
    });
```

I appreciate any help, as Ive only been successful with AJAX forms that don't share a button before.
thanks!

*also, how would I add a fourth conditional that if all elements are filled out, display error message "You can only submit one at a time"***

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the validation plugin for jQuery: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: as I said I dont have trouble with validation on ready, but haven't been able to get this to work as a submit function

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a function to submit, however you still need to call $("#formOne").submit() after you run your validation.

ie:

$("#formOne").submit(function() {
            // run your validations

```
        if (valid) $(this).submit();

    });
```

Comment: You would put your validations either in another function or inline after the comment that says "// run your validations" the last line the if (valid) was designed to be an example of checking a boolean value and then submitting the form. Hope that makes sense.